# Cannot make FadeIn and FadeOut act synchronously?

Tags: jquery, effects

I'm trying to use jquery to animate between two images, fading one out then fading the other in.

However, I cannot get them to act syncronously, the fadeIn() always gets called before the fadeOut() is complete:
`$(function() {
            var tabContainers = $('#tabwrap > div');
            var listItems = $('#tabwrap ul.tabnav li');
            listItems.click(function() {
                var second = tabContainers.filter($(this)[0].title);
                tabContainers.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    second.fadeIn('slow');
                });`

```
            $('#tabwrap ul.tabnav').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            return false;
        }).filter(':first').click();

        listItems.hover(function() {
        });
    });
```

`<div>
        <div id="tabwrap">
            <div id="tab1">
                Tab1</a>
            </div>
            <div id="tab2">
                Tab2</a>
            </div>
            <div id="tab3">
                Tab3</a>
            </div>
            <div id="tab4">
                Tab4</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="tabnav">
                <li title="#tab1" style="cursor: pointer;">Tab1</li>
                <li title="#tab2" style="cursor: pointer;">Tab2</li>
                <li title="#tab3" style="cursor: pointer;">Tab3</li>
                <li title="#tab4" style="cursor: pointer;">Tab4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>`

Any ideas?

Cheers, Ed

Comment: This code works as designed on my machine, tested with Firefox 3.5.7 using jQuery 1.2.5 or 1.3.2 and in IE8 using jQuery 1.3.2.  By works as designed, I mean fading one out completely before fading the other in.

Comment: Hmm. I'm on firefox 3.5.7 and it's not working. I'll try getting a newer version of jquery.

Comment: Nope, not working on my pc or my co-worker's, using various different versions of jQuery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you are calling the `fadeOut` function, some of your items are already faded-out so that it is firing immediately.

The code below is tested and works, but can be refined considerably more. I'll leave that to you:

```
var tabContainers = $('#tabwrap > div');
var listItems = $('#tabwrap ul.tabnav li');
tabContainers.hide();
var $selectedDiv = $("#tab1").show();

listItems.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $myDiv = $("#" + $this.text().toLowerCase());
    if ($selectedDiv.attr("id") != $myDiv.attr("id")) {
        $selectedDiv.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $myDiv.fadeIn('slow');
        });
        $selectedDiv = $myDiv;
    }

    $('#tabwrap ul.tabnav').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Never been a legend before. Its a great feeling! ;-)

Comment: haha, that's been a major headache for a while: I've had to mess with your code though, you've assumed that my lovely antiseptic test scenario was like real life and used the <li> content as an identifier: in real life this actually has meaningful information, hence the use of the title attribute. Nothing too problematic though ;)

Comment: Its an assumption I made in the code, but not in my head. As you hinted, it wasn't the important bit. Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

The code as written...

```
tabContainers.fadeOut('slow', function() {
    second.fadeIn('slow');
});
```

explicitly calls `fadeIn()` after `fadeOut()` is complete.  You're passing fadeIn it as a callback to the second parameter to fadeOut, to be executed on completion.

Have you tried this?

```
tabContainers.fadeOut('slow');
second.fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Yes: I'm trying to get them to act synchronously, i.e. have the fadeIn take place *after* the fadeOut, and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try queuing the animation instead of running it on callback:

```
tabContainers.fadeOut('slow').queue(function() {
    second.fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Comment: This has exactly the same issue I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get jQuery to wait for animation to end is the `promise()` method. Which, is great when another section of the code needs to wait and you don't have a handle on the objects you're supposed to wait for, you can get them with a jQuery selector and then call promise to wait on all of the returned objects to finish.

E.g. `$('.animating').promise().done(function( arg1 ) { 
  alert( "Done animating.");
});`